# Emacs: using geiser and Racket

Tags: emacs, racket, geiser

My .emacs file contains this line of code:

```
(setq geiser-racket-binary "C:/Program Files/Racket/Racket.exe")
```

My steps:

1. M+x run-geiser
2. Select racket
3. I get errors, "Searching for program: No such file or directory, Racket.exe"

Getting this to work has been a hassle and, maybe at this point, I am just missing something ridiculously easy, but I am just not seeing it.

[Picture of my error messages and file path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQVI6.png)

I am using a PC.

Answer (score 1):

Without getting a chance to look at your PC and see if you if you actually have Racket installed at that location, I suspect the problem is that you are using forward slashes (`/`) rather than back slashes (`\`) in your path. Try changing the line to:

```
(setq geiser-racket-binary "C:\\Program Files\\Racket\\Racket.exe")
```

Another solution would be to use [racket-mode](https://github.com/greghendershott/racket-mode) to edit your files rather than Geiser. It seems to do a better job at editing Racket files in Emacs.

Comment: Maybe need double backslashes -- `"C:\\Program Files\\Racket\\Racket.exe"`?